# Html image source from a local folder on windows options

Tags: php, html

On my html page, I make use of images which are housed in a local folder. The paths are coming directly from the database field. How can I do this? I know it wont work if the images are not in the web root directory. Can symlinks work?

For example,

The physical path to the images is `c:/Images` and the database field will contain the path like this, `photo/image1.jpg`

I will fetch the image source path from php as shown below,

```
<img id="image1" src="<?php echo $this->object->imagePath; ?>" class="img-polaroid">
```

`$this->object->imagePath` here will be the string concatenation of `c:/Images` and `photo/image1.jpg`. So, putting it together t will be `c:/Images/photo/image1.jpg`

The problem is it does not show up. I have tried this as well to test,

```
<img id="image1" src="file:///C:/Images/photo/image1.jpg" class="img-polaroid">
```

But no luck.

Comment: what do you mean by local folder? can you show us some of your path examples and your intention

Comment: Does your image actually exist at that path?  You should simplify your question... if the last example doesn't work, then your question has nothing to do with PHP or anything.

Comment: Try copying the images folder into your root directory and using `<img id="image1" src="<?php echo {"/images"}$this->object->imagePath; ?>" class="img-polaroid">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first let me know if putting just **C:/Images/photo/image1.jpg** in a browser address bar brings an image or not. If not then that's mean you are giving wrong path. Let me know so i can edit this answer. But for now this is the answer i hope.

Comment: Yes it works. It converts the url into file:///C:/Images/photo/image1.jpg and displays the image

Comment: Well! then check your page source code in browser and see what it has coded in src of your img. Check if that's exactly what you are expecting

Comment: The weird part is. When i create a sample test html page and render the image from there it works fine. But not through this zend framework 2 application. The page source shows exactly the same path i give. When i copy paste the link in the browser it works. Not from the application.

Comment: Ok. Now i got your problem hold on

Comment: Well! I tried to make some Jugars but the reason is that when you run application from Zend, it is on localhost and as due to on localhost it cannot access your pc's personal other files. You didnt mention that about Zend on initial stage that's bad.:(

Comment: Thats was exactly the problem! Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

Symlink to the folder worked like a charm.